# Node.js Sequelize: Cannot delete property 'meta' of [object Array]

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, sequelize.js

I'm learning the Sequelize.js framework and it's pretty awesome. But when I try to remove a column from my test tables in in my migration file, I get this error:

`ERROR: Cannot delete property 'meta' of [object Array]`

This error occurs when I use the removeColumn function from the query interface but I don't have an idea why ...

My migration file:

```js
'use strict';

const {DataTypes} = require("sequelize");
/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
  async up (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.sequelize.transaction(t => {
      return Promise.all([
        queryInterface.removeColumn('Students', 'bloodStatus', {transaction: t}),
      ]);
    });
  },

  async down (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.sequelize.transaction(t => {
      return Promise.all([
        queryInterface.addColumn('Students', 'bloodStatus', {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: false
        }, {transaction: t}),
      ]);
    });
  }
};
```

I used the migration file above but I get the error

```
ERROR: Cannot delete property 'meta' of [object Array]
```

I read the documentation and tried to find a solution, but unfortunately I can't find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution! I use a MariaDB in a docker container (10.11.2-MariaDB-1:10.11.2+maria~ubu2204 - mariadb.org binary distribution) and the dialect in the config.json was set to mariadb as shown in the code example below:

```js
{
  "development": {
    "username": "christian_cornwall",
    "password": "hogwarts",
    "database": "hogwarts_sequelize",
    "host": "172.17.0.3",
    "dialect": "mariadb"
  },
  "test": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_test",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mariadb"
  },
  "production": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_production",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mariadb"
  }
}
```

After changing the dialect settings to mysql (if you don't have the package installed, it'll ask you to install mysql2 via npm) the error's gone and the removeColumn function works. I hope this will help somebody!

Comment: Thanks. I have the exact problem. Sequelize 6. What bothers is that mariadb package and dialect works fine in the application only failed in migration. Good catch.

Answer (score 3):

While the solution from Chipmaster5 works, I think it's a bad idea to use mysql dialect, if you're using a mariadb image. Specifically this problem seems to be introduced with v3 of the mariadb package, reverting to 2.x resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error:

```bash
% node migrate.js
Running migrations...
{ event: 'migrating', name: '20230628090200-drop-column-id.js' }
Dropping column memberServiceId from table member_service_node
/myproject/node_modules/umzug/lib/umzug.js:151
                    throw new MigrationError({ direction: 'up', ...params }, e);
                          ^
MigrationError: Migration 20230628090200-drop-column-id.js (up) failed: Original error: Cannot delete property 'meta' of [object Array]
    at /myproject/node_modules/umzug/lib/umzug.js:151:27
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Umzug.runCommand (/myproject/node_modules/umzug/lib/umzug.js:107:20)
    at async file:///myproject/data/migrate.js:105:3 {
  cause: TypeError: Cannot delete property 'meta' of [object Array]
      at Query.formatResults (/myproject/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mariadb/query.js:110:7)
      at Query.run (/myproject/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mariadb/query.js:73:17)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at async /myproject/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:315:16
      at async MySQLQueryInterface.removeColumn (/myproject/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query-interface.js:27:23)
```

Until mariadb@3 is supported

```bash
npm install mariadb@2 --save
```

... solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case i solved this problem by just using raw queries (`queryInterface.sequelize.query([raw query]`) instead of the "removeColumn" abstraction.